# Using typeof vs === to check undeclared variable produces different result

Tags: javascript, operators

If I have an undeclared variable and use `typeof` it tells me it's `undefined`.
But if I then check it using `if (qweasdasd === undefined)` it throws an exception.

I don't understand this behavior, because if the first tells `undefined`, then the second check should evaluate to `if (undefined === undefined)`, why does it throw a ReferenceError exception?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/y1xhw9un/

Comment: @Jamiec — Can reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/y1xhw9un/1/

Comment: @Quentin - ahh, thats *undeclared*, When it is undefined, then it works http://jsfiddle.net/y1xhw9un/2/

Comment: @Jamiec: In that snippet, you covertly defined `y` to have value `undefined`. OP is asking about a case when the variable is undefined, not when it has value `undefined`. "undeclared" does not exist as a term in JavaScript; the error message is "ReferenceError: ... is not defined".

Comment: @Amadan - No, it appears (from Quentins sample) the OP has an undeclared variable - that's quite different to undefined. I think your answer is right thogh - `typeof` is letting you "get away with it" where the equality check isnt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`typeof` looks like a function call, but it is not - it is an operator. Operators are allowed to break rules. `typeof(qweasdasd)` does not assume `qweasdasd` exists; whether it exists or not and what it is is what `typeof` exists to discover. However, when you test `qweasdasd === undefined`, you are using `qweasdasd` as a value, and JS complains when you use a variable that you haven't assigned a value to.

Comment: But isn't it a lie to say that `qweasdasd` is an `undefined`? Because then in my mind the `if` check is perfectly valid and should evaluate to `if (undefined===undefined)`.

Comment: JavaScript is a bit confusing here (and it's not the only place; don't get me started on the insanity of `sort`). As I said, being undefined and having the value `undefined` are two different things, an unfortunate situation exacerbated by the fact that `typeof(qweasdasd)` and `typeof(undefined)` both produce the same result.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to give up on understanding the logic of javascript.

Comment: Why does `typeof` behave differently than, for example, unary `+`?

Comment: The logic? It was a language created in 10 days, that got landed a monopoly on browser environment, which ended up freezing it against backward-incompatible modifications. I am *astounded* it is in as good a shape that it is.

Comment: @SalmanA: As I said, operators *can* break rules. `&&` and `||` break rules by lazily deciding whether or not to evaluate the second argument; `typeof` breaks rules by not caring whether or not a variable has been defined. `+` was created to evaluate both arguments and also to care about variable being defined. It does not break rules; no-one said all operators have to be weird.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to read the value of an undeclared variable (which you have to do before you can compare that value to the value of `undefined`) throws a ReferenceError.

Applying the `typeof` operator to an undeclared variable does not.

Comment: Why does `typeof` behave differently than, for example, unary `+` (e.g. `+foo -> boom!`)?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a very simple explanation for this -- because the specs say so:

- [`typeof` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) is not supposed to throw the ReferenceError exception if the variable is not defined

> 2. If Type(*val*) is Reference, then
>      a. If IsUnresolvableReference(*val*) is **true**, return `"undefined"`.

- [`===` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.4) is supposed to throw the ReferenceError exception if the operand(s) refer to undefined variables

> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
>
> *[And inside the definition of GetValue we have]*
>
> 2. Let *base* be the result of calling GetBase(*V*).
> 3. If IsUnresolvableReference(*V*), throw a **ReferenceError** exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have an undefined variable, but not an undefined object value.

```
console.log(variable) // undefined
console.log(typeof variable) // "undefined"
console.log(variable === undefined) // Reference error
variable = undefined ; 
console.log(variable === undefined) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to access undefined variable in Javascript gives `ReferenceError`. `typeof` is working because it not accessing variable value. Its checking its type.

[**typeof**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) not requires defined variable. Its parameter should be an expression representing the object or primitive whose type is to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` is an operator that returns you a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand. It doesn't matter if the unevaluated operand is undefined or not.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

```
>>> if (a !== 'undefined');
Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: a
>>> if (typeof a !== undefined);
undefined
>>> if (typeof a !== void 0);
undefined
```

Comment: `typeof(parseInt)`: `"function"`. But `typeof(typeof)`: `SyntaxError`. `typeof` is *not a function*; if it *were* a function, it would give `ReferenceError` just like `parseInt(qweasdasd)` does.