# understanding Javascript Typeof

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, undefined

When I execute below code , it prints "undefined" two times.
I was expecting that it would raise error since variable is not defined and also there is use strict' statement in the top.

```
'use strict';
var a;

console.log(typeof a);
console.log(typeof b);
```

Can anyone explain why it is not raising an error ?

Comment: because that's how it works...

Comment: Simply `undefined`  means that the variable isn't yet defined, that's the normal behavior.

Comment: 'typeof' never raises error: if a variable is undefined, it returns "undefined". By design.

Comment: This is not related to `node.js`.. Will behave exactly same in the browser!

Comment: related, if not duplicate: [Using typeof vs === to check undeclared variable produces different result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31671887/1048572), [How does typeof circumvent the ReferenceError when supplied an undeclared variable identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29155472/1048572), [How can I determine if a JavaScript variable is defined in a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/138669/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact in JavaScript `undefined` means that the variable isn't yet defined, so basically :

- `typeof a` returns `undefined` because the variable `a` was only declared but not initialized yet (there's no value assigned to it).
- And `typeof b` returns `undefined` because the variable `b` is not yet declared, so isn't defined.

And if there's no value assigned to a variable, it gets the type `undefined` because as type can't be determined.

So if you check the **[MDN typeof specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)** you will see that :

> The `typeof` operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand, and if you see types table you can see that `undefined` is a primitive type and one of the possible return values of `typeof`.

**Examples:**

And you can see in the **Examples** section, the undefined return:

> // Undefined
>
> typeof undefined === 'undefined';
>
> typeof declaredButUndefinedVariable === 'undefined';
>
> typeof undeclaredVariable === 'undefined';

**Note:**

*And as stated in comments this is only related to JavaScript syntax and doesn't have anything to do with nodejs.*

Answer (score -1):

You don't use a function from "a", nor do you use any functions wich excepts a parameter, wich isn't undefined. Typeof only checks for the memory location of the variable.

Answer (score -1):

`undefined` is a [primitive data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures),

and that's one of the possible options the `typeof` operator can return,

the other options it can return are:

- `boolean`
- `number`
- `string`
- `function`
- `object`
- `symbol`